# 3" Electrical box has diagonal mounting holes. Need horizontal. Any adapters?

Tags: electrical

I have a couple of bathroom light fixtures above the mirrors. They are mounted to 3" boxes with diagonal mounting screws in opposing corners of the box. My light fixtures have the mounting holes horizontal. Are there adapters for this? Again, the boxes are old 3" electrical boxes with holes 2.75" apart.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such an adapter exists -- its called a "universal" or "all-purpose" crossbar, and looks like this:

[image: all-purpose crossbar]